# iOS 5 - Coredata Sqlite DB losing data after killing app

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, core-data

I'm using coredata with a sqlite DB to persist data in my app. However, each time I kill my app I lose any data that was saved in the DB. I'm pretty sure its because the .sqlite file for my DB is just being replaced by a fresh one each time my app starts, but I can't seem to find any code that will just use the existing one thats there.
It would be great if anyone could point me towards some code that could handle this for me.

Cheers

B

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
{
    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber     numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];    
NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"FlickrCoreData.sqlite"];

NSError *error = nil;
__persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}    

return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Comment: You must use the same ManagedObjectContext whenever you are writing to the store. How are you writing data to the moc and how are you passing the ManagedObjectContext around to the other controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changes to a managed object context in core data are not saved at the time you make the changes for optimization purposes.  This way you can make a bunch of changes to your context and then persist all the changes at once.  So if you are killing your app before it has a chance to autosave you will then lose all your data.  I'm guessing this is what you are experiencing here.

In any case, try explicitly making a call to save your data before closing your app.  This should solve your problem.

For example, assuming you have a variable that holds your managed object context called `context` you can save your context by making the following call somewhere in your code before closing the app:

`[context save:&error]` or simply `[context save:nil]`

Comment: Hi Jake, my AppDelegate does call save on the context from the applicationDidTerminate method. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yea - didn't want to tell you exactly where to put the save call because that should be up to you depending on what best fits your program structure.  However, I would say put it in one of the 'Will...' delegate methods, ie `applicationWillTerminate` - this way you give the program a little time to actually make the save.

Comment: Thanks for that. I actually had to call '[context save:&error]' from 'applicationDidEnterBackground'. According to the docs "If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits."

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried place `[self saveContext]` in appDelegate function `applicationWillTerminate:`. You should save the context before terminate the application.

Comment: What is this code for ? `NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];` I think the default one is nil?

Comment: Its to handle data migration when you update the version of the datamodel. I tried it with nil as the value instead of options but it makes no difference.

Comment: I don't think the database will generate a new one every time the app start. I think the problem is you insert the data to coredata and forgot to save the context. Can you posted code where you insert the data to coredata?

Comment: Thanks Lunayo. I managed to figure out my problem. Solution posted above.